# Convergence $ \ell^1$ sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, functional-analysis

if I have a sequence $(x_n) \in \ell^1$ and an element $x \in \ell^1$ and we have that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}: x_n(k) \rightarrow x(k)$, does this mean that $||x_n-x||_1 \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: No, it does not.

Answer (score 5):

No.

Hint: sliding bump.

> $x_n(k)=\delta_{n,k}$